# Storekit configuration file for UITest

Tags: swift, uitest, storekittest

I created `Configuration.storekit` file, and it work for Run on ios simulator.
But when i'm trying to run UITest, it always fails on initing `SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "Configuration")` with error:

```
caught error: "Error Domain=SKTestErrorDomain Code=4 "File not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=File not found}"
```

Here is my code

```
import XCTest
import StoreKitTest

class MyProjectUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let session = try SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "Configuration")
            session.disableDialogs = true
            session.clearTransactions()
        }
        // UI tests
        
        *****
        
    }
}
```

If i'm trying to `@testable import MyProject` it fails with another errors:

```
Missing required modules: 'Amplitude', 'FBSDKCoreKit', 'Firebase'
```

I even tried to add `Target Membership` for `Configuration.storekit` file in MyProjectUITests target.

Can anyone say, how could I init `SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "Configuration")` without getting errors?

Comment: Problem was solved after xCode update =)

Answer (score 3):

To solve the "File Not Found" I added the `.storekit` file to the Test-Bundle.

- Make sure you use the right XCode Version, as @Dmitrii mentioned. I'm currently at 12.3
- In addition, make sure to add the `.storekit` to the test-bundle:

  - Open the `.xcodeproj` file
  - Click on your Test-target
  - Go to tab "Build Phases"
  - At "Copy Bundle Resources" add the `.storekit` file

Not sure, if these are all the required steps to get it running.
At least the `SKTestSession` finds the configuration file now.

Comment: It was enough for me to add the file to the Copy Bundle Resources phase; I didn't have to add ".storekit" to the name passed to `SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed:)`.